# WPF / metro - how to make a WebBrowser / WebView control ignore all input from user

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, webbrowser-control, microsoft-metro

Basically, I want to have a WebView (similar to WebBrowser in WPF) on top of of a ScrollViewer control to take advantage of some ScrollViewer functionality, but I don't want users to be able to interact directly with the WebView with the mouse or touch events. Instead, the events should go to the ScrollViewer to be handled.

However, putting the WebView before, inside, or after the ScrollViewer doesn't work. Setting the IsHitTestVisible property to false for the WebView control also doesn't work.

Comment: No, Windows 8 "metro"/Windows RT WebView -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do that with the built-in WebBrowser, but you should be able to do it with [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/). It supports "windowless rendering", so there's no window handle to take focus, which means it's not going to accept any keyboard or mouse input unless you manually direct them its way.